# Pass generic list to stored procedure using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@myList";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.Value = datatable;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.TypeName = "tblTempBaseFileInsert";

var outPutList = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("spInsertToBaseFile @myList", param).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error :

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, perhaps obtusely, is telling you simply that the stored procedure is returning multiple columns of data, but you're trying to cast everything to an `int`. You need to create a class that maps to what your stored procedure is returning and use that as the generic type param to `SqlQuery`. For example, if you're getting columns named `Foo` and `Bar` back:

```
public class MyListDto
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var outPutList = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyListDto>("spInsertToBaseFile @myList", param).FirstOrDefault();
```